# Problem with editing order in Shopware admin panel when custom discount is added

Tags: php, shopware, shopware6

I wrote custom cart discount according to the documentation https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-discounts
Everything works fine, discount is recalculated when customer add or remove products from his cart but when I want to edit this order in admin panel I receive error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Exception\LineItemNotStackableException: "Line item with identifier "CHEAPEST_ITEM_CART_DISCOUNT" is not stackable and the quantity cannot be changed." at /var/www/shop/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Cart/LineItem/LineItem.php line 233 {"exception":"[object] (Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Exception
> LineItemNotStackableException(code: 0): Line item with identifier "CHEAPEST_ITEM_CART_DISCOUNT" is not stackable and the quantity cannot be changed. at /var/www/shop/vendor/shopware/core/Checkout/Cart/LineItem/LineItem.php:233)"} []

I "solved" this by add in code this checking:

```
if($behavior->hasPermission(self::SKIP_PROMOTION)){
        $items = $original->getLineItems()->filterType(self::LINE_ITEM_TYPE);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $toCalculate->add($item);
        }
        return;
    }
```

Now, if I edit order in admin panel, error doesn't show up but discount is not calculated again and switch "Disable automatic promotions" doesn't work.

Is there any solution to recalculate custom discount in order in edit action?
When I add new order in admin panel everything works fine, problem is only on edit.
Documentation doesn't say anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

Find if the discount was already added to the cart by the referencing the identifier. If it was, simply remove the old instance from the cart before adding the recalculated discount.

```php
if ($original->has($discountLineItem->getId())) {
    $original->get($discountLineItem->getId())->setRemovable(true);
    $original->remove($discountLineItem->getId());

    return;
}

// $discountLineItem->getType() should equal LineItem::DISCOUNT_LINE_ITEM
$toCalculate->add($discountLineItem);
```

In addition you'll have to make sure your processor is executed after Shopware's own `PromotionProcessor` or otherwise it will try to re-add the discount you previously added manually.

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Cart\CustomPromotionProcessor">
    <!-- ... inject after default discount cart processor (3700) -->
    <tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="3600"/>
</service>
```

I [created an example plugin](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneDiscountExample) that includes all the changes from the guide necessary for the recalculation. Tested on the current release candidate for `6.5` but should also work in latest version of `6.4`.

That example is based on having a discount in form of a percentage of the cart value. If the discount is supposed to be a varying absolute value the procedure is slightly different. I [created a branch in the aforementioned repository](https://github.com/dneustadt/DneDiscountExample/tree/absolute-discount) with an example for that as well.

Comment: We tried a similar approach `$existingDiscount = $toCalculate->getLineItems()->filterType(self::LINE_ITEM_TYPE)->first();
if ($existingDiscount) {
    $toCalculate->get($existingDiscount->getId())->setRemovable(true);
    $toCalculate->remove($existingDiscount->getId());
}` but our discount is not present in `$toCalculate` cart only in `$original`. But even removing it from both doesn't help. We can edit our order, but when we try to flip the "Disable automatic promotions" weird things are happening. I'm afraid that this is a problem with Shopware itself.

Comment: Have you tired it like suggested? The exception is thrown when the quantity of a non-stackable item is increased. Either something tries to change the quantity explicitly, or more likely, the discount just gets added multiple times which would increase the quantity as well. Your discount will have to be in the calculated cart at some point for this to occur and if this is a completely custom discount, Shopware will not add it by itself. What even is the value of `self::LINE_ITEM_TYPE`? Filtering by the type might not yield an exact match.

Comment: self::LINE_ITEM_TYPE is the name of our discount. When I filter $original this way I'm getting our discount. We created a discount using https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-discounts, but it's missing some key elements like using the $behavior parameter.

Comment: For now the only part we have a problem with is switching the "Disable automatic promotions" in order edit, but I'm not sure what it should do in the first place. When I switch it first time it duplicates the promotion and after second time it returns 500 with the same error "Line item with identifier ... is not stackable".

Comment: I think I can see what the problem might be. I think your custom processor might be executed prior to Shopware's own `PromotionProcessor`. That default processor then tries to re-add your custom discount and that's where the exception is thrown. You have to use a lower priority so your processor runs afterwards. Then remove the discount from the calculated cart (via the id, so you really only remove your own, custom discount) and you should be able to add it again. I'll update my answer on how to change the priority.

Comment: Our processor service has lower priority `<tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="4500"/>`

Comment: Ok, the idea was right. You have to remove the old discount, but as you mentioned, from the `$original` cart and then one must return early for the next calculation iteration. Also the tutorial is wrong about the type. It says something like `example_discount` but the type should only be one of the defined by constands of `LineItem`. In this case it would be `LineItem::DISCOUNT_LINE_ITEM` and it matters. Furthermore you have to set the priority lower than `DiscountCartProcessor`. Updated the answer and also added an example plugin with all the changes on GitHub.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253004/discussion-between-saint-and-dneustadt).

Comment: Judging from the name of the discount I figured what you want is an absolute value for a discount instead of a percentage. So I provided an example for that as well in form of a branch of the example repository. Really just to prove, that it can be done without having that issue of non-stackable items. Sorry, but I can't invest more time at this moment. Hope this helps nonetheless.